start sections on odd pages and customise blank even pages
I want that new sections in my document start on odd pages only and if it has to skip a page because it is even, then i want to have headers and footers blanked. In my MWE, not sure why these skipped even pages have the title of the section that is to start in the following page only, in the header/footer where i inserted it (\fancyfoot[C]{\titresection}).
Possibly, these even pages could have a piece of text like "oOoOo" or an image in the center...
I tried to insert a blank page after the TOC but it is failing.
If possible I want section titles in the document to be not bold and with a custom size.
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox,xstring}
\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr,lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

% commence les section uniquement sur une page impaire
% (utilisation de 'etoolbox')
\newif\ifoddsections
\pretocmd{\section}{
 \ifoddsections 
 \ifnum\value{section}=0\relax
  \else
    \cleardoublepage
   \fi
 \else
\fi}{}{}


\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{header}}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\titresection}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage{} / \pageref{LastPage}}

\fancyfoot[C]{\titresection}

% enlève le numéro de section
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\oddsectionstrue

%\newpage  %% <=== leads to lualatex complaint and hanging

\def\titresection{partie 1}
\def\lieu{lieu 1}
\def\titreanx{versets 1-xx}

\section[\titreanx]{\titresection~(\lieu)}


\lipsum[1-16]
\newpage
\def\titresection{partie 2}
\def\lieu{lieu 2}
\def\titreanx{versets yy-zz}
\section[\titreanx]{\titresection~(\lieu)}

\lipsum[10-18]
\end{document}


Why are you using article and \section instead of book and \chapter?

if you think that is going to solve problems completely or partly please go head and make that change. I do not have much knowledge about the technical advantages of book and \chapter

Use emptypage and redefine its \emptypage@emptypage command (if you want some ornament in the added pages).
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr,lastpage}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{header}}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\titresection}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage{} / \pageref{LastPage}}
%\fancyfoot[C]{\titresection}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

% commence les section uniquement sur une page impaire
\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\cleardoublepage}

% enlève le numéro de section
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}
\makeatother

% ornament for empty pages
\makeatletter
\def\emptypage@emptypage{%
  % original is
  %\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi
  % we don't need the two column part
  \vspace*{\fill}\centerline{\Huge oOoOo}\vspace*{\fill}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\titresection{}
\def\lieu{}
\def\titreanx{}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\def\titresection{partie 1}
\def\lieu{lieu 1}
\def\titreanx{versets 1-xx}

\section[\titreanx]{\titresection~(\lieu)}


\lipsum[1-16]
\newpage

\def\titresection{partie 2}
\def\lieu{lieu 2}
\def\titreanx{versets yy-zz}
\section[\titreanx]{\titresection~(\lieu)}

\lipsum[10-18]
\end{document}



i said text or image in the center of the page, that right you did it but actually I was thinking that it would still allow defining the header/footer for custom use. I tried a \fancyhead[C]{VvVvV] after \thispagestyle{empty} but that left the the header empty and put "VvVvV" in the center of the footer. Could you make this change?

@user1850133 You can define a suitable page style, call it emptypage and issue \thispagestyle{emptypage} as part of the command.
